# Could this cause a memory leak, returning array from function?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-leaks, return

I have the following code which works fine except I'm not sure if I need to delete the `returned_array` pointer in the `int main()` or if its automatically deleted. I will guess its not automatically deleted and assume I should use `delete returned_array;` after the `cout` is finished. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>

double* pass_return_array(double passed[])
{
        double* returned_array = new double[3];

        for(int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
            returned_array[index] = passed[index];

        return returned_array;
}
int main()
{
        double passed[3];
        double* returned_array;

        for(int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
            passed[index] = index + 100;

        returned_array = pass_return_array(passed);

        for(int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
            std::cout<<returned_array[index]<<std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It most likely is when the program ends, but you should anyway. The true lesson is to use `std::vector` or something. It deletes the memory for you.

Comment: "It most likely is when the program ends, but you should anyway." You mean I need to delete it.

Comment: Yes, you should. That comes into play a lot more when you repeatedly claim a resource without giving it back. For an example of something that can't clean itself up by the OS when your program ends, how about a half-finished database transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: you created the array in the function, you also are responsible for its deallocation. You should call `delete[] returned_array;` as soon as you no longer need it.

Note, that OS always cleans up all resources allocated by the program when it terminates, so there won't be any *system-wide* memory leaks. But it's a *very bad* practice to leave the deallocation to the OS, you should always deallocate all resources you allocated (and that includes other kinds of things - for example handles to files or brushes).

Consider using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead - if used as a simple local variable, they will take care of memory they allocated and you won't have to remember about it. That's the power of C++ in work :)

Comment: did you mean `delete[] returned_array;`

Answer (score 2):

It's good practice to clean up all resources that you allocate regardless of whether or not you think it will be done automagically for you.

It's also good practice for the responsibility for a resource to follow the resource itself. That means, if you return some dynamically allocated memory from a function, you also "return" the responsibility for it.

That's not to say it has to be cleaned up in the function caller since that may break encapsulation (you don't necessarily even *know* if it's dynamically allocated). But, even if you pass the resource back to the code/library that created it, that is again passing the responsibility too, as per the following pseudo-code:

```
def makeSomething():
    something = unknownMethodForCreatingSomething()

    #makeSomething() has responsibility here but passes it off to caller

    return something

def killSomething(something):
    # Responsibility with killSomething() at this point

    equallyUnknownMethodForDestroyingSomething(something)

def main():
    xyzzy = makeSomething()

    # main() has responsibility for xyzzy here but hands it off in next line

    killSomething (xyzzy)
```

Comment: Shouldn't killSomething destroy `something` instead of creating another instance?

Comment: @Spook, yes, you're right. Damn that cut'n'paste :-) Fixed it up.